# Acceder a BD mySQL desde una red externa (trabajo - hogar)

Tags: java, mysql, android, sql, servidor

Quisiera saber si existe la manera de formar un servidor y poder conectarme con la aplicación de Android ya sea desde mi casa o con los datos móviles.

Las especificaciones de mis sistemas son las siguientes:

- Tengo una computadora de buenos componentes donde solo tengo en ejecución XAMPP y una conexiona a internet de 100MB con fibra optica
- Tengo una BD en mySQL que opero por XAMPP en la cual se conectan 2 programas de PC (JAVA) y 1 de Android (Android Studio - Java).

Lo que busco es conectar es poder acceder a mi base de datos desde fuera de mi red local, ya que se encuentre en Baja Califormina y quisiera poder usar la aplicación desde California y tener acceso a los datos en todo momento.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, puedes hacer un servidor MySQL al que accedas a la base de datos. Para ello necesitas varias cosas:

- Abrir los puertos de tu router y redirecionar la entrada del puerto a tu ordenador (para que cuando conectes con el router conecte con tu ordenador).
  Cada router es diferente por lo que no te puedo guiar mucho aquí... Lo que te puedo recomendar es buscar el manual del moderlo de tu router que suele estar debajo del router o detrás
- Asegurarte de no tener ningún problema con el firewall para que no te bloqueen conexiones (puede que no te de ninguno, pero es mejor tenerlo en cuenta para futuros fallos o problemas)

Cuando tengas esas 2 cosas podrás conectarte a tu servidor mediante el puerto abierto previamente. Para conectarte a tu router tienes que conseguir tu ip pública de tu router, para ello te recomiendo que desde tu ordenador vayas a una página como [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/) en la que te dirán la ip pública de tu router.

Luego para configurar en la conexión a la base de datos tendrás que poner `mi_conexion.setServerName("234.46.53.12")` donde `234.46.53.12` sería tu ip pública sacada de [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/) anteriormente.

> Por defecto el puerto de **MySQL** es el **3306**

**Edición:**

**Explicación más detallada de como funciona:**

Un router tiene 2 ip's. Una ip privada y una pública.

- **Ip privada:** Es la ip de tu red local (Ejemplo: 192.168.0.1)
- **Ip pública:** Es la ip para conectarse a internet, por así decirlo "la ip externa" (Ejemplo: Cuando en el **cmd** haces un `ping www.google.com` te pone su ip pública que en mi caso me sale que es `172.217.16.228`)

Para averiguar tu ip pública la manera más rápida que hay es visitando [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/) o una página parecida ya que tu cuando te conectas a una página web, te conectas a través de tu router y el servidor recibe la ip pública de tu router

**¿Porque www.google.com y no `172.217.16.228`?**

A esto se le llama **dominio** y se suele contratar ya que la gente no se va a acordar de `172.217.16.228` y si de `www.google.com`.

Básicamente, un **dominio** es la redireción de una cadena de caracteres a una IP, estos dominos los gestionan los **DNS**

**Conclusión:**

Cuando abres un puerto de tu router y lo redirecionas hacia tu ordenador (por ejemplo el 3306 que es el de MySQL, por defecto) conectaras esa base de datos de MySQL de tu ordenador y todo aquel que tenga la IP de tu router y los accesos a tu base de datos podrá acceder a tu base de datos. **Esté donde esté**

Comment: Pero esto seria solamente para entrar cuando me encuentre en la misma red o no?.

El proposito es poder consultar la base de datos por medio de la aplicacion Android estando lejos de la PC que ejecuta XAMPP, osea, poder tener la PC en Mexico y yo estar en EUA pero seguir accediendo a esta.

Comment: Un comentario se me quedaba corto para explicártelo y que lo entendieses, así que he editado la pregunta. Cualquier duda, no dudes en preguntar

Answer (score 0):

- Desconozco que proveedor de servicio de Internet tengas y como lo
  dice en la respuesta anterior cada router se configura de manera
  distinta en mi caso mi ISP es TELMEX y te vas en la opción de mapeo
  de puertos y ahí seleccionas la aplicación que en este caso es
  servidor Mysql y seleccionas el host interno donde este tu servidor.
- Tambien es importante y como lo mencionaron anteriormente es
  importante no tener problemas con el firewall y abrir el puerto 3306
  en tu PC. Y te quedaria algo asi

[image: ISP]

- Otra cosa importante es crear un usuario en mysql para que    este se
  pueda usar de manera externa en cualquier red

Usando el siguiente comando:

```
CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
```

El **%** indica que puede ser cualquier host de cualquier red

Y para otorgarle los privilegios

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'%';
```

En este caso otorga todos los permisos en todas las bases de datos y en todas las tablas

Y por ultimo asegurarse de refrescar los privilegios con el comando

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Y por ultimo seria modificar el string de conexión (desconozco la sintaxis)...
que seria algo asi

```
servername="ip_publica";
user="el_usuario_que_creaste";
password="";
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda, sino a seguir investigando y si sigues teniendo dudas, no dudes en preguntar.